# How to put result from multiple statements in assocaitive array

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to have a profile page where you can view your friend connections, each "friend" shows the profile pic, username, name and surname, number of "friends" and number of posts. I am fetching the results using ajax get. The only way I could get the results to work in phpmyadmin was through 2 select statements. When running it in my php I cannot get the result to work with an associative array. Here is my code:

```
$json = '{"people":[';
        $sql = "SELECT u.uUsername, u.uName, u.uSurname, u.uProfilePic, u.User_ID, COUNT(c.Conn_ID) AS Conns
                FROM tbusers u INNER JOIN tbconnections c
                ON u.User_ID = c.connected OR u.User_ID = c.connector
                WHERE c.connector = $user OR c.connected = $user
                GROUP BY u.User_ID;
                
                SELECT COUNT(n.Post_ID) AS Posts
                FROM tbusers u INNER JOIN tbconnections c
                ON u.User_ID = c.connected OR u.User_ID = c.connector
                INNER JOIN tbposts n
                ON n.User_ID = u.User_ID
                WHERE c.connector = $user OR c.connected = $user
                GROUP BY u.User_ID";                    
        if($conn->multi_query($sql)) {
            do {
                if($result = $conn->store_result()) {
                    $res = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                    foreach ($res as $row){ var_dump($row)                              ;
                        $json .= '{"username" : "'.$row['uUsername'].'", "name" : "'.$row['uName'].'", "surname" : "'.$row['uSurname'].'",'.
                            ' "pic" : "'.$row['uProfilePic'].'", "uid" : "'.$row['User_ID'].'", "conns" : "'.$row['Conns'].'"},';
                        }
                }
            }
            while($conn->more_results() && $conn->next_result());
            $json = substr($json, 0, strlen($json) - 1);
            $json .= ']}';
            echo htmlspecialchars($json, ENT_NOQUOTES);
```

And the result I get from the var_dump is:

> array(6) { ["uUsername"]=> string(11) "Einsteinium" ["uName"]=> string(5) "Charl" ["uSurname"]=> string(6) "Meyers" ["uProfilePic"]=> string(24) "images/profilePics/1.jpg" ["User_ID"]=> string(1) "1" ["Conns"]=> string(1) "1" } array(6) { ["uUsername"]=> string(5) "Pinky" ["uName"]=> string(7) "Mariska" ["uSurname"]=> string(6) "Meyers" ["uProfilePic"]=> string(24) "images/profilePics/4.jpg" ["User_ID"]=> string(1) "4" ["Conns"]=> string(1) "2" } array(6) { ["uUsername"]=> string(6) "Sannie" ["uName"]=> NULL ["uSurname"]=> NULL ["uProfilePic"]=> NULL ["User_ID"]=> string(1) "5" ["Conns"]=> string(1) "1" } array(1) { ["Posts"]=> string(1) "6" }

Yet I still get the following notices when running, note that it says undefined index even though I use the correct index:

> Notice: Undefined index: uUsername in C:\xampp\htdocs\IMY\Project\profileChange.php on line 182
>
> Notice: Undefined index: uName in C:\xampp\htdocs\IMY\Project\profileChange.php on line 182
>
> Notice: Undefined index: uSurname in C:\xampp\htdocs\IMY\Project\profileChange.php on line 182
>
> Notice: Undefined index: uProfilePic in C:\xampp\htdocs\IMY\Project\profileChange.php on line 183
>
> Notice: Undefined index: User_ID in C:\xampp\htdocs\IMY\Project\profileChange.php on line 183
>
> Notice: Undefined index: Conns in C:\xampp\htdocs\IMY\Project\profileChange.php on line 183

It also seems that it outputs the second select statement in `var_dump($row)`:

> array(1) { ["Posts"]=> string(1) "1" }

The json string does in fact contain the data I want, but with 3 extra results in it:

> {"people":[{"username" : "Einsteinium", "name" : "Charl", "surname" : "Meyers", "pic" : "images/profilePics/1.jpg", "uid" : "1", "conns" : "1"},{"username" : "Pinky", "name" : "Mariska", "surname" : "Meyers", "pic" : "images/profilePics/4.jpg", "uid" : "4", "conns" : "2"},{"username" : "Sannie", "name" : "", "surname" : "", "pic" : "", "uid" : "5", "conns" : "1"},{"username" : "", "name" : "", "surname" : "", "pic" : "", "uid" : "", "conns" : ""},{"username" : "", "name" : "", "surname" : "", "pic" : "", "uid" : "", "conns" : ""},{"username" : "", "name" : "", "surname" : "", "pic" : "", "uid" : "", "conns" : ""}]}

I know I am not doing this right, what is the propper way of doing it?

Comment: do **NOT** generate json manually. there's `json_encode()` for a reason...use it.

Comment: Is this because of security of performance issues?

Comment: no. because you're at risk of the JS equivalent of sql injection attacks - you're doing it manually, which means YOU have to do EVERYHING necessary to generate syntactically valid JS. instead, build a plain regular PHP data structure, then json_encode() it. that'll do all the hard work, and you just sit back and relax.

Comment: Oh I see, yea the reason why I do not cater for that is because my website handles the get request, but yea it is still open for attacks

Comment: doesn't matter. you're stuffing arbitrary text into what has to be valid js. consider `"name":"John "The Meister" Doe"`. oops... syntax error.